# Why is a 60/40 bond/equity mix not doing well?

Tags: stocks, mutual-funds, bonds

The Vanguard Wellesley Income Fund (VWINX) is known as a highly conservative mutual fund composed of approximately 60% bonds and 40% equities.

In the current markets, this seems like a good conservative mix.  But why is VWINX performing poorly over the last 6 months, as bond and equity prices have both increased?

Comment: "VWINX performing poorly" compared to what?

Comment: I don't know what's in that fund, but the/an obvious answer is the "mix" might be fine (40%/60%), but the specific bonds and equities in each part might be the "wrong" ones (for some definition of "wrong" ... if they are looking for long-term gains, six month dips may not matter). In a similar vein, "_performing poorly over the last 6 months_" should be followed by "_compared to what_".

Comment: Bonds prices fall when interest rates rise, and interest rates have been rising.

Comment: The majority of bond ETFs are down this year.  For example, the IShares 20+ Year Treasury Bond ETF (TLT) is down 7+ pct this year and nearly 10% in the past 6 months.  Why would you expect VWINX with 60% exposure to fixed to perform well in such an environment?

Comment: Weak dollar, higher rates. It was all over the news for last year.

Comment: What are you looking at to come to the conclusion that bond prices have increased?  The yields have increased, that's different.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the graph and found a drop of $0.52 after the dividend of 15th December 2017. Since the dividend was $0.2145 that would explain half that drop. Perhaps someone else can explain the remainder.

Large drops have occurred at other VWINX dividend dates too. I have read that the drop as shares go ex.div can be reduced by the tax paid by a typical investor. But VWINX is behaving in the opposite way!

Comment: The distribution on 12/18/17 was 52 cents (Div + STCG + LTCG) and VWINX dropped 52 cents (adjusted close).  Paragraph two is confusing.  The drop isn't reduced by taxation.  The value of your position is.

Comment: Yep. That explains the 15th December drop and the previous drops I saw. Confidence restored. I hope the questioner is happy with his distribution-:)

Answer (score 0):

Over the past 6 months, VWINX has returned more than 2% better than a pure bond ETF like AGG (though both have negative return over this time period).

Since broad stock indices have done well over the last 6 months, it seems the VWINX is performing as expected.